# Pandas Dataframes vs. Dask Dataframes (Memory)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dask

I was comparing the loading speeds of a Dask Dataframe vs Pandas as we are dealing with larger datasets and Pandas can have some timely delays (i.e. 10GB+ files).

I ran a quick experiment below where I used the time.time() to look at the time it takes for Pandas to load data vs Dask and I was suspicious behind the efficiencies between the two (Dask shows 100x improvement which seems absurd as Pandas is generally quite efficient).

Reading the documentation, I understand that Dask focuses on Partitions and how it 'breaks' down a large dataframe into a series of subsets, but is this sufficient for a 100x difference in speed?

Could this be due to Dask perhaps *not* actually loading the dataframe into memory or is it just partitioning the file and remembering where to go get parts of it when it needs to? (i.e. pointer)

I'd appreciate it if anyone could explain this.

I've included a small snippet of the data here as well.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tlHH7CS0kROwtLLq1jYAgWTevK_0C6qq/view?usp=sharing

Thanks very much!

[image: Dask DF]
[image: Pandas_DF]

Comment: Yes, `dd.read_csv` will not load the whole data. It's a lazy dataframe that will be evaluated when required further downstream.

Comment: Also, please include real code in your question, not images or links to code. The laziness of dask collections is covered extensively in the docs, tutorials and other questions, so voting to close.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev Thanks for confirming my suspicions. So essentially constructing a bunch of file pointers that then partition.

Comment: @mdurant Thank you for calling this out and letting me know. I will update the Q accordingly.